# How to make login as other user in API using laravel passport?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

I am using laravel passport for API authentication. and I want to log in as different users with different roles from superadmin. So how can I achieve this? Please give your suggestions.

```
   public function masqueradeNotary($profileId)
   {
     $userId = decodeC($profileId);
     $notaryUser = $this->adminService->getUser($userId);

     if($userId){

        //logout from current login user
        $user = auth()->user()->token();
        $user->revoke();

        //login as notary user
        $userRoles = $notaryUser->roles()->get();
        
        // $scopes = [];
        // if ($userRoles) {
        //     $scopes = Arr::pluck($userRoles,'code');
        // }

        if(Auth::login($notaryUser)){
            \Log::info("auth user");
            \Log::info(auth()->user());
            // $token = $user->createToken($user->email . '-' . now(), $scopes);
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Bryant I have added code of this flow.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should look at [spatie's package](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction), it might make your life easier.

You can apply roles on the registration if you create two different registration functions. In the front-end, you have to somehow make the user decide and pass that value (a checkbox would be ideal).

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. there is no need to check auth login just log out the current user and revoke the access token and create a token for the user directly.

```php
$token = $user->createToken($user->email . '-' . now(), $scopes);
```